# What can be the cause of poor performance of my neural network on testing data, but a very high accuracy on the training data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've made an attempt at developing a simple model to tackle a multi-classification problem. I've found a dataset on Kaggle of 25k+ tweets labeled with sentiment of the text (positive, neutral, negative). I've processed the data and came up with a simple model of a network. The network reaches around 98-99% accuracy on the training data, but around 60% on the testing data. What could be the cause of such discrepancy between the performance, and how can I optimize the model to achieve better evaluation performance?

Here is the code:

```python
df = pd.read_csv('Tweets.csv');

df = df.drop(columns=['textID', 'selected_text'])

data = df['text']
labels = df['sentiment']

labels = np.unique(labels, return_inverse=True)
lookup = labels[0]
labels = labels[1]

data = np.array(data).astype(str)
tokenizer = keras_preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
one_hot_results = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(data, mode='binary')

all_tweets = one_hot_results[:20000]
all_labels = labels[:20000]

train_data = all_tweets[:10000]
test_data = all_tweets[10000:]


train_labels = all_labels[:10000]
test_labels = all_labels[10000:]


model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000, )))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_data, train_labels, batch_size=512, epochs=20, validation_split=0.3)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
print("test_acc:", test_acc)
```

Here is my console output:

```
Epoch 19/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.0423 - accuracy: 0.9903 - val_loss: 1.9351 - val_accuracy: 0.6063
Epoch 20/20
14/14 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.0365 - accuracy: 0.9920 - val_loss: 2.0434 - val_accuracy: 0.6013
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 1.9856 - accuracy: 0.6086
test_acc: 0.6086000204086304
```

I've tried changing the amount of layers, their size, batch size, amount of epochs, adjusting the vocabulary size of the vectorized test data, but nothing seems to improve the evaluation.

Comment: This is overfitting and not a programming problem, you can find many techniques if you search for it, there is no specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Meh, the biggest problem I see there is that your model is not suitable for the problem.
You are doing the a text clasification, for this kind of problem you have several options:

1. A 1D CNN.
2. A RNN like LSTM.
3. Use more complex models that are based on transformers.

Here is a basic model you can use for text classification:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, input_length=max_seq_length))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very common, and it happens due to overfitting. Your model may learn the training dataset very well but not be able to generalize well to the test dataset.

The main reason why your model is not achieving high accuracy is type of neural network you are using. A simple fully connected architecture is not very good for most ML problems. You should learn about sequential models like LSTMs and GRUs, or Transformers. Here is a great course by Andrew Ng from Stanford: https://www.coursera.org/learn/nlp-sequence-models.
Depending on your experience with ML, you may need to check out its precursors. If you don't feel like taking a long course, you should look at Keras documentation to see examples of implementations of LSTMs and Transformers.

If you still are not satisfied with your accuracy, @feelsgood 's response contains some useful methods that have been historically used to alleviate overfitting. You try experimenting with hyperparameters in dropout, regularizers, and such. In the end, the best and easiest—although not always possible—way to overcome overfitting is by getting more data. If you can't find any other datasets, you can try using data augmentation techniques. I don't know if there are any well-known data augmentation techniques for sentiment classification, but you can probably experiment with adding filler words and replacing words with synonyms in inputs.

Answer (score 0):

25K observations is a small amount of data for a complex model especially with a non-negligible number of parameters: in this case two hidden layers and an input-shape of 10K.  The model can basically *memorize* the inputs.  You have not added any *dropout* or *regularization* and you did not do *early stopping* as the other answers mention so there's nothing to prevent being able to recreate the training data almost exactly.

But then your model has not really learnt any ability to *generalize* the data. It has not found patterns in the data instead when asked "what's next?" it just regurgitates what you already fed it.